# Plotlegends and filenames

Tags: import, legending

I have data files which are in "text tab delimited". I have imported these files using the following function:

```
data = Map[Import[#, "Data"] &,FileNames["*.txt", {"directoryname"}]]
```

I want to use ListPlot to plot 60 functions (not at the same time), but I want to show the name of the files that I have imported in the PlotLegends so that when I plot each file, the legends automatically show the name of the file.

Here is the rest of the code:

```
e[t_] := data[[t]];
ListPlot[Table[e[t][[9]], {t, 1, 59, 20}], Joined -> True, PlotRange -> All,DataRange -> {1000, 1100},PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

Thanks

Comment: [Edit your question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/posts/223500/edit) to include that information, instead of leaving it in the comments.

Comment: @saeid: Welcome to Mathematica SE. I've not totally understood what you old like to do. In your `ListPlot` a selection of files is chosen and their and (only) this filenames should be in the legend, right?

Comment: @mgamer: yes that is right

Comment: @saeid: O.K. I've  put this as an answer below

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that I understood your right... making my toy-data and the filenames

```
data = Table[RandomInteger[200, 20], {60}];
files = StringJoin["data", #, ".csv"] & /@ (ToString /@ Range[60])
```

export...

```
Export[#[[1]], #[[2]]] & /@ ({files, data}\[Transpose]);
```

Get the data in, similar like you did:

```
inFiles = FileNames["*.csv", NotebookDirectory[]];
data = Flatten /@ (Import[#] & /@ inFiles)
```

Taking a random sample

```
toPlot = RandomInteger[60, 5]
```

Doing the `ListPlot` with appropriate filenames

```
ListPlot[data[[toPlot]], Joined -> True, 
 PlotLegends -> (inFiles[[toPlot]])]
```

[image]

If you want only the filenames, without the directory, you have to strip of the directory, you can use something like (there are a lot of different ways):

```
StringCases[#, "data" ~~ x__ -> "data" ~~ x] & /@ inFiles
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is an alternative solution that uses the fact that the `PlotLegends` are automatically populated when the data are passed in as an [`Association`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Association.html):

Using the example data from @mgamer's answer:

```
data = Table[RandomInteger[200, 20], {60}];
files = StringJoin["data", #, ".csv"] & /@ (ToString /@ Range[60])

Export[#[[1]], #[[2]]] & /@ ({files, data}\[Transpose]);

inFiles = FileNames["*.csv", Directory[]];
```

The import is done using [`AssociationMap`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AssociationMap.html) - this way, the file names are kept together with the data from the start. We use [`KeyMap`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/KeyMap.html) and [`FileNameTake`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FileNameTake.html) to extract only the file name without directory:

```
data = Flatten /@ KeyMap[FileNameTake]@AssociationMap[Import, inFiles]
(* <|"data10.csv" -> {44, 160, 52, …}, "data11.csv" -> {171, 63, 89, …}, … *)
```

Now a simple call to [`ListLinePlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListLinePlot.html) generates the required plot, together with the legend:

```
ListLinePlot[data[[{1, 2, 3}]]]
```

[image]

Since it is an [`Association`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Association.html), you can also specify the files to plot by the keys (i.e. file names):

```
ListLinePlot[data[[{"data10.csv", "data11.csv", "data12.csv"}]]]
(* same output *)
```

Answer (score 2):

@saeid: I would look at the documentation around `LegendLabel`.  You have a list of files (`FileNames["*.txt"]`), an indexed list of data, so your final plot will look something like `ListPlot[e[#][[9]], ... , LegendLabel->file[[#]]]& /@ Range[1, 59, 20]`